# Sqllite - IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:

Tags: sqlite, data-integrity

I am wondering why in the following example my Sqllite3 in Python command does not work:

I am creating the following table

```
query = """
  CREATE TABLE customers2 (
      "customer_id" serial PRIMARY KEY,    
      "name" VARCHAR UNIQUE,
      "name2" VARCHAR UNIQUE,
      "email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
      "active" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
      constraint test unique(name, name2)
)
"""
cur.execute(query)
```

Then I am inserting some values

```
 query = """
    INSERT INTO customers2(name, name2, email)
    VALUES 
       ('IBM', 'a','contact@ibm.com'),
       ('Microsoft','b', 'contact@microsoft.com'),
       ('Intel', 'c','contact@intel.com');
 """
 cur.execute(query)
```

Then I would like to insert a combination of name = "Microsoft" and name2 = "a" which values already exist but not in combination. The following command gives an error

```
 query = """
   INSERT INTO customers2 (name, name2, email)
   VALUES('Microsoft','a','hotline@microsoft.com') 
   ON CONFLICT (name, name2) 
   DO UPDATE SET name2 = name2+"b";
 """
 cur.execute(query)
 IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: customers2.name2
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: You specified that name2 is unique but it isn't.

Comment: But how to specify that the combination between name AND name2 needs to be unique?

Comment: I know that the values 'microsoft' and 'a' exist but not in the combination

Comment: Well it seems you already did that. But you specified additional constraints for the individual columns. Have you tried omitting them?